# How to render a template and layout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In a controller method, how can you render a template and layout?

Like so:

```
def new
  render :template => 'devise/invitations/new', :layout => 'application_unauthorized2_t2' 
end
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of just being an options hash, like most rails methods, the render method is a series of arguments, the *last* of which is an options hash.  The first argument to render is the template, as a string.  You don't need to include it in the options hash.

Just do this:

```
def new
  render 'devise/invitations/new', :layout => 'application_unauthorized2_t2' 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a [Class level layout method](http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Layouts/ClassMethods/layout)

Comment: This is useful only if you want the entire controller to use one layout.

Comment: You're wrong. For instance - layout :another, :only => [:new, :edit]

Comment: I'm not definitively wrong here.  It's not the simplest way to do this, and it doesn't answer the question - "In a controller method."  Yes, it works.  Is it the best choice?  No.  It's a very roundabout way of handling it.

Comment: Your comment is wrong, not the answer. And I didn't read the question thoroughly :)

Comment: I know, that's what I was responding to.