# How to render a specific layout while rendering a specific template using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use a specific layout when rendering a specific template.
Here's an example code below.

```
// app/controllers/errors_controller.rb

def website_template
  if xxx
    return "front/layouts/404
  elsif yyy
    return "front/layouts/404" <-- I want this to use application_other.html.erb while rendering 404.html.erb template.
  end
end
```

How can I do so?
I've tried below, but none of them seem to work.

```
elsif yyy
  render template: "front/layouts/404", layout: "front/layouts/application_other"

elsif yyy
  return "front/layouts/404", layout: "front/layouts/application_other"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5984987/3975479
This will answer your question.

Comment: Can you share your whole ErrorsController? Also did you follow this guide? https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.0/action_controller_overview.html#custom-errors-page

Comment: what are you trying to do using putting that inside some method? under normal circumstance `render template: "front/layouts/404", layout: "front/layouts/application_other"` should be working. show us where the website_template part called might help to understand better

Comment: You specify layouts by  [using the `layout:` option](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#the-layout-option) exactly like you are doing. If you want debugging help you need to give us an real [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of just some psuedocode. Its very likely that you will solve the problem yourself when extracting out the MRE.